# Is it possible to replace a ceiling fan speed controller with a switch?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

Is it possible to replace a ceiling fan speed controller with a switch? I just bought a house that had a ceiling fan with no light, which used a fan speed controller on the wall with different speeds. I added a light to the ceiling fan and would like to replace the fan controller with a light switch, that will turn both the light and the fan on. You would have to control each with the chains that hang from the fan. I replaced the fan controller with a light switch and it didn't work. Does it need to be connected differently? I only connected the 2 black wires and the ground. It is a one pole switch.

Comment: There is 2 wiree in the box is 14-2. (one is hot)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this. The fan speed controller should have 2 terminals, swap it with a single pole switch.  If it's a digital controller it might also have a neutral - just put a wire nut over it and only connect the switch between the hot wires.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a wireless remote? Replace the fan speed controller with a switch. Install the remote contoller between the fan and the and the ceiling box. A handheld battery remote controls fanspeed and lights with dimming They have them at most home centers. They cost about $35.